# Oracle OBIEE (BI): export result of analysis without hidden columns to CSV

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

I have an analysis which contains hidden one column. While I'm trying to export result to .xlsx file, it works right, and hidden column doesn't print and calculation works fine. But when I'm trying to export it to .csv - either with ';' delimeter or tab-delimeter - hidden column appears.
There is no opportunity to exclude this column from analysis defenition because of field that I need to calculate, that has strong dependence on hidden column. Also I can't keep it in that form and remove column and add calculation by myself because this file after export automatically will be imported to database which has not enough space to make such operation every month till forever. Is there any way not to print hidden column and save prepared calculation while exporting to CSV?

Answer (score 0):

No. CSV exports exactly what's in the analysis. That's its point and task. You can always clone your analysis, prepare the columns as you need and then just expose it as a download link.

CSV = exact, pure raw data as it's in the analysis construction

Excel = formatted based on what's rendered visually